# Issue using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am trying to find out all the followers of a given user.
I find the following code:

```
User u1 = null ;
    long cursor = -1;
    IDs ids;
    System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
    do {
        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs("NZ_Football", cursor);
        for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
            System.out.println(id);
            User user = twitter.showUser(id);
            System.out.println(user.getName());
        }
    } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

The piece of code works perfectly for me. However, I have questions:

1. what is a cursor value for? Why it is -1 here?
2. It will hits the limit rate if the user's followers list is huge.
3. what is the ids.getNextCursor() for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@1. The cursor value is a kind of flag if it is -1, that means there are still some followers of a particular user. The twitter API uses this cursor mechanism because it returns a set of follower IDs for each loop.

@2. Yes, but you can figure out this issue. You can create several twitter account to generate  some new token stuff. Then, you can implement a mechanism that renews the token whenever rate limit shows up.

@3. It returns the cursor value of the new set of follower IDs. As far as I remember, it returns 50000 IDs per loop.

I hope I replied all you want to know well.

Comment: That is great. So you mean that the cursor value will be only -1 and 0? -1 means there are still something, and 0 means it have reach the end?

Comment: The cursor can have values other than `-1` and `0`. Also, I would not recommend using multiple tokens - it sounds like an easy way to get banned from the API. Finally, the API call can return a maximum of 5,000 results per request.

Comment: @jonathan, why dont you offer better idea to fix rate limit issue? Because I am an academic researcher, the time is important for me and I cannot wait for rate limit. Also you wrote that the cursor can have other than -1 and 0 but below in your answer you also wrote there are two cursor values you should be aware of, -1 and 0. Finally, I can say that you are not honest.

Comment: @MehmetGokhanBAKAL I was just advising caution on the use of multiple tokens. Regarding the cursor - it starts at `-1` and ends at `0`, in between it can be any number except for those two reserved values.

Comment: @Jonathan, please say a better idea to fix rate limit without waiting because you are claiming having more than one token is not a good idea. Tell me better solution though.

Comment: @MehmetGokhanBAKAL Perhaps Twitter, or one of their [data resellers](https://dev.twitter.com/programs/twitter-certified-products/products#Data) can help with data for academic research.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor allows results to be broken up into "pages" or groups or results. this is useful when it would be infeasible to get all results at once; for instance if the user has millions of followers.

The cursor can be thought of like a page number in a book. Specifying it in the request tells Twitter what page of results you want returning. However, unlike page numbers, cursor values are non-contiguous. This is why Twitter sends you the 'next cursor value' in the response:

```
cursor = ids.getNextCursor()
```

This is Twitter telling you what the next page number is so you can use this in your next request to get that page of results.

The cursor may be set to any value; however, there are two reserved values you should be aware of, `-1` and `0`:

- `-1` is the starting value, it signifies that you want results to be paginated (some API mandate cursoring) and Twitter will send the first page of results.
- `0` signifies that Twitter does not have any more pages to send: you've just had the last page and do not need to make any more requests.

Regarding rate limiting, you will hit problems for users with a large numbers of followers if you do not manage your requests sensibly.

The `getFollowersIDs` API is restricted to returning a maximum of 5,000 results and you can only make 15 of these requests in a 15 minute window. So, if a user has more than 75,000 followers, you will need to ensure you schedule the requests somehow, e.g. make a request per minute.

More detailed information can be found in Twitter's documentation, specifically, [`GET followers/ids`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids), [cursoring](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) and [rate limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).